# Java generics how to avoid interface cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments

Tags: java, generics

Here's the scenario.

Our app has a very trivial interface for cache implementations, with methods similar to a Map:

```
public interface ICache<K, V> {
```

To add a concrete cache implementation we implement the interface and wrap a cache framework like EHCache, Redis, memcached etc. Example (the fact that its EHCache here is immaterial to the question):

```
public abstract class EHCacheWrapper<K,V> implements ICache<K, V> {
```

Next we have an implementation of EHCacheWrapper called AuthenticationCache:

```
public class AuthenticationCache 
   extends EHCacheWrapper<AuthenticationCacheKey, AuthenticationCacheEntry> {
```

So far so good.

The AuthenticationCache object has some additional methods beyond EHCacheWrapper or ICache. What we want to add are interfaces for AuthenticationCache, AuthenticationCacheKey, and AuthenticationCacheEntry:

```
public interface IAuthenticationCacheKey extends Serializable {
public interface IAuthenticationCacheEntry extends Serializable {
public interface IAuthenticationCache extends ICache<IAuthenticationCacheKey,IAuthenticationCacheEntry>{
```

So now we have:

```
public class AuthenticationCache 
   extends EHCacheWrapper<AuthenticationCacheKey, AuthenticationCacheEntry> 
   implements IAuthenticationCache {
```

Which gives the compiler error:

```
The interface ICache cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments: ICache<AuthenticationCacheKey,AuthenticationCacheEntry> and ICache<IAuthenticationCacheKey,IAuthenticationCacheEntry>
```

How do I achieve what we're after here?

Comment: You cannot implement the same interface with different generic bounds. The only ways I see fixing this are: --- to make the `IAuthenticationCache` generic in `K extends IAuthenticationCacheKey, E extends IAuthenticationCacheEntry` and let it implement `ICache<K, E>`... I think you get the point or --- let `AuthenticationCache extends EHCacheWrapper<IAuthenticationCacheKey, IAuthenticationCacheEntry>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I implement Comparable more than once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685537/how-can-i-implement-comparable-more-than-once)

Comment: Turing85 your suggestion worked - I changed IAuthenticationCache interface as follows: public interface IAuthenticationCache<K extends IAuthenticationCacheKey,E extends IAuthenticationCacheEntry> extends ICache<K, E> {

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As generics are no longer available at run time because of [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) it can't be distinguished between two implementations of `ICache<K, V>`. You need to re-consider the design of you Interface and class hierarchy. Is it really necessary that `IAuthenticationCache` extends `ICache`?

```
public interface IAuthenticationCache
//extends ICache<IAuthenticationCacheKey,IAuthenticationCacheEntry>
{ ... }
```

Comment: Yes because it gets passed into another object that accepts ICache - but I understand your point and agree I need to reconsider the design here